# Categorical approach to form of simple representation of product of groups

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory, monoidal-categories, adjoint-functors, functors

Throughout, $\mathsf C_1,\mathsf C_2$ are small categories and $\mathscr V$ is a bicomplete symmetric monoidal closed category.

I'm trying to understand some of the basic theory of group representations. [This blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2009/08/30/the-orthogonality-relations-for-representations-of-finite-groups/) by Qiaochu Yuan points out the internal hom on the category of representations acts as a "categorified inner product". This makes the picture much more conceptual for me.

However, now I'm struggling to understand how to see the fact that simple representations of a product of groups come from the outer tensor product of simple representations of their factors.

1. I tried to understand [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/18007/69037), but I'm still missing something. Given two representations $F_1:\mathsf C_1\to \mathscr V$ and $F_2:\mathsf C_2\to \mathscr V$ the assignment $F_1,F_2\mapsto F_1\boxtimes F_2;\eta,\mu\mapsto \eta\boxtimes \mu$ given by applying the tensor product of $\mathscr V$ pointwise yields a functor $$[\mathsf C_1,\mathscr V]\times [\mathsf C_2,\mathscr V]\overset{\boxtimes}{\to}[\mathsf C_1\times \mathsf C_2,\mathscr V].$$ The latter inherits a symmetric monoidal closed structure from $\mathscr V$ and so we have the composite
   $$([\mathsf C_1,\mathscr V\times [\mathsf C_2,\mathscr V])^\text{op}\times [\mathsf C_1\times \mathsf C_2,\mathscr V]\overset{\boxtimes^\text{op}\times 1}{\longrightarrow}[\mathsf C_1\times \mathsf C_2,\mathscr V]^\text{op}\times [\mathsf C_1\times \mathsf C_2,\mathscr V]\overset{\mathsf{hom}}{\longrightarrow}\mathscr V.$$ By symmetry of products and Cartesian-closedness of $\mathsf{Cat}$ we obtain a functor $$\mathrm H:[\mathsf C_1\times \mathsf C_2,\mathscr V]\longrightarrow[([\mathsf C_1,\mathscr V]\times [\mathsf C_2,\mathscr V])^\text{op},\mathscr V]$$ defined on objects by $$\mathrm H(F)= \mathsf{hom}(-\boxtimes=,F):([\mathsf C_1,\mathscr V]\times [\mathsf C_2,\mathscr V])^\text{op}\to \mathscr V.$$ The claim is then that this functor is representable when $F$ is simple. Then, by enriched Yoneda for $\mathsf C_1\times \mathsf C_2$ we somehow deduce that a simple $F$ has the form $F_1\boxtimes F_2$ for simple $F_1,F_2$. Why can we do this?
2. I also tried to understand [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/18004/69037) to the same question. Namely that given a factor $F_1$ we can get the other one using some sort of $\mathsf{hom}(F_1,F)$. This is a little confusing to because I read it as $ \left\langle F, F_1 \right\rangle$ and that shouldn't provide information about $F_2$, and also because I don't see how to give this internal hom the structure of a representation of $\mathsf{C_2}$. On the other hand, the previous question sort of hints at this by using an "internal tensor-hom adjunction" on $H(F)$, but I also don't see how to make any sense of that.

If anyone could illuminate these things to me, that'd be great.